# how to add "p" in file

Tags: awk, csv

I have `test.csv` file and below is the content

```
"A","b","c","d"
```

I wanted to add `"p"` between `b` & `c` using `awk` command, could you please assist?

Comment: Welcome, have you tried something so far?

Comment: why awk? Why not sed, perl, python, something else?

Comment: Do you want to add the new column between the columns `b` and `c`, no matter what two columns these are (how do we deal with them not being next to each other?), or do you want to add it in the middle of 4 columns as a new third column?  If the text is static, why don't you just `echo '"A","b","p","c","d"' >file`?

Comment: position to add new values is not fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{$2=$2",""\"p\"";print }' filename

"A","b","p","c","d"
```

Comment: Or even quite simplified answer to a quite simplified question: `'{print $1,$2,"p",$3,$4}'`